# How to highlight the search using the code below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, html-lists

The code below already does a letter search between the li. And I wanted to highlight the letters in research in li. Is it possible using the code below?

```
<input type="search" id="catInput">
<ul id="myUl">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Javascript</li>
</ul>
<span id="total"></span>

<script>
var ip = document.getElementById('catInput');
var ul = document.getElementById('myUl');
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "" + (li.length) + "";
ip.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var val = this.value.toUpperCase(), idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var txt = li[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
    if (txt.indexOf(val) != -1) {
      li[i].style.display = '';
      idx++;
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    if (idx == 0) {
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "No results";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = idx;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code within the `if (textIndex != -1) {}` condition, it'll add the [`mark`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) tag to the matched input:

```
const rgxVal = `(${val})`;
const rgx = new RegExp(rgxVal, 'gi');
li[i].innerHTML = txt.replace(rgx, `<mark>$1</mark>`);
```

I've also removed `toUpperCase()` from `txt` and `val` and only add it when testing for a match:

```
const textIndex = txt.toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase());
if (textIndex != -1) {
  ...
```

**Demo:**

```js
var ip = document.getElementById('catInput');
var ul = document.getElementById('myUl');
var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "" + (li.length) + "";
ip.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var val = this.value, idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var txt = li[i].textContent;
    
    if(val) {
      var textIndex = txt.toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase());
      if (textIndex != -1) {
        li[i].style.display = '';
        const rgxVal = `(${val})`;
        const rgx = new RegExp(rgxVal, 'gi');
        li[i].innerHTML = txt.replace(rgx, `<mark>$1</mark>`);
        idx++;
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    } else {
      idx = 3;
      li[i].style.display = '';
      li[i].innerHTML = txt;
    }
  }
  if (idx == 0) {
     document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "No results";
  } else{
     document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = idx;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="search" id="catInput">
<ul id="myUl">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Javascript</li>
</ul>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you. There's only one problem. When searching for any letter and delete it is between the letters <mark></ mark>. See https://ibb.co/6WY13qt